# Power via another computer

Tags: server

I am 13 and am considering putting Ubuntu on my parents old computer, however it is very slow. I was wondering if I could make it so their computer uses part of my computers power (I have a fast computer) but I still get to use windows. So my computer in a way hosts two computers with 2 different OSs.

Thank you!

Comment: Probably your best options are to either run Ubuntu within windows on Virtualbox or run an alternate, light weight distro on the old box (lubuntu or tinycore).

Comment: No, but you can install both operating systems on your computer and choose which one you want each time you turn the computer on. This is called "dual booting" and there are hundreds of howtos around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As bodhi.zazen mentions, the easiest way is to just put a light OS on the less powerful machine. Other options will require a lot more work.

Dual booting as terdon suggests only lets you use one OS at a time, which from my understanding of your question is not what you are looking for.

You can also run some kind of virtualization software on your more powerful computer. Install Ubuntu as a virtual machine. With Ubuntu on the less powerful machine, you can either remote into the virtual machine with something like VNC, or do something like X11 forwarding. This will mostly utilize the CPU and hard drive speed of the more powerful computer. Graphics performance in a situation like this won't be helped much, and it depends on the network.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am going to try VNC seeming I got a bit of spare time on my hand :D!